# How to expand text search on class properties to include numeric text comparision

Tags: c#

I have the following functionality that searches string based properties on a class for a text match, I would like to expand this to include numeric properties. I only want to do a text comparison rather than match an exact number.

Some advice on how best to cache variable properties would be handy too.

```
public bool Match<T>(T item, string searchTerm)
{
    //You should cache the results of properties here for max perf.
    IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> properties = GetPropertyFunctions<T>();
    bool match = properties.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.Contains(searchTerm));
    return match;
}
public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

    var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetPropertyFunc<T>);
    return properties;
}

public Func<T, string> GetPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, string>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
    Func<T, string> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
    return propertyAccessor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var stringProperties = GetStringPropertyFunctions<T>();
    var decimalProperties = GetDecimalPropertyFunctions<T>();
    return stringProperties.Concat(decimalProperties);
}

public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetStringPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

    var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetStringPropertyFunc<T>);
    return properties;
}

public Func<T, string> GetStringPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, string>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
    Func<T, string> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
    return propertyAccessor;
}


public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetDecimalPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)).ToList();

    var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetDecimalPropertyFunc<T>);
    return properties;
}

public Func<T, string> GetDecimalPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, decimal>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
    Func<T, decimal> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
    return (T item) => propertyAccessor(item).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Made one more question for the caching of properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908126/how-to-cache-the-following-variable-that-holds-class-properties