# How to cache the following variable that holds class properties

Tags: c#

I have the following functionality that searches string based properties on a class for a text match, I would like to cache the 'properties' variable in Match() so it doesn't get refreshed every time I run through a list of class objects.

```
public bool Match<T>(T item, string searchTerm)
{
    //You should cache the results of properties here for max perf.
    IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> properties = GetPropertyFunctions<T>();
    bool match = properties.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
    return match;
}

public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var stringProperties = GetStringPropertyFunctions<T>();
    var decimalProperties = GetDecimalPropertyFunctions<T>();
    return stringProperties.Concat(decimalProperties);
}

public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetStringPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

    var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetStringPropertyFunc<T>);
    return properties;
}

public Func<T, string> GetStringPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, string>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
    Func<T, string> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
    return propertyAccessor;
}


public IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetDecimalPropertyFunctions<T>()
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)).ToList();

    var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetDecimalPropertyFunc<T>);
    return properties;
}

public Func<T, string> GetDecimalPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, decimal>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
    Func<T, decimal> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
    return (T item) => propertyAccessor(item).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class FullTextSearch<T>
{
    private List<Func<T, string>> _properties;

    static FullTextSearch()
    {
        _properties = GetPropertyFunctions<T>().ToList();
    }

    public bool Match(T item, string searchTerm)
    {
        bool match = _properties.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
        return match;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make properties a private field and use the Lazy Wrapper to initialize it on first use.
You have to make the other methods static to use it like this, but that should be easily possible.

```
private Lazy<IEnumerable<Func<T, string>>> properties = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Func<T, string>>>(GetPropertyFunctions<T>);

public bool Match<T>(T item, string searchTerm)
{
    bool match = properties.Value.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
    return match;
}
```