# How to filter child collection with linq dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to filter results for user request.
For instance you have `orders` and `order details` and `products` is child collection.

When user wants to filter by product I'm getting an error because of `No property or field 'PRODUCTS' exists in type 'ICollection`1'`

I'm writing my query like this.

```
var orders = _uow.Repository<ORDERS>()
    .Query()
    .Where("PRODUCTS.HEADING.ToLower().Contains(\"foo\")")
    .Include("ORDER_DETAILS")
    .Include("ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCTS")
    .ToList();
```

So it's not possible to filter child collection like this? Or any way to filter?

Thanks.

Comment: You don'y need to do .Inculde("ORDER_DETAILS"), it is enough to do .Include("ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCTS"). You can try without the .Include("ORDER_DETAILS") line and see what happens.

Comment: Order of the tables like ORDERS -> ORDER_DETAILS -> PRODUCTS. So I have to include ORDER_DETAILS because that contains productID.

Comment: I understand, but pleasse take a look at [msdn examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx), they say that, in your case for example, ORDER_DETAILS will be included if you only do .Include("ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCTS").

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now (good to know that, thanks). But problem still same.

Comment: The problem is that ORDER_DETAILS is a list, and each order detail has a list of product, isn't it? This is why you get the error message. Do you see, in order to get products from ORDER_DETAILS you will need to iterate through it and get the products from each element. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: I have added an answer, according to the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way you named your classes/properties it's hard to guess which one is a single object and which one is a collection property.

If `ORDERS` class property `ORDER_DETAILS` is a collection of `ORDER_DETAILS` class, and `ORDER_DETAILS` class property `PRODUCTS` is a singe object of `PRODUCTS` class having a string property `HEADINGS`, then the following should do the trick:

```
.Where("ORDER_DETAILS.Any(PRODUCTS.HEADING.ToLower().Contains(\"foo\"))")
```

It's basically the same as static query with lambda parameters skipped

```
.Where(o => o.ORDER_DETAILS.Any(d => d.PRODUCTS.HEADING.ToLower().Contains("foo")))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I was not realize it is that simple to use entity framework ANY expression with linq dynamic.

Comment: Quick question, can I use where condition with order by also? Is the usage same?

Comment: I guess so, but not 100% sure. It's trial and error experience, you know :)

Comment: It turns out that it's not supported:( Neither "FirstOrDefault` and similar. Basically the only supported are `Any`, `All`, `Count`, `Min`, `Max`, `Sum` and `Average`.

Comment: Yea when I write any or firstordefault it gives "No applicable aggregate method 'FirstOrDefault' exists" error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ORDER_DETAILS is a list, and each order detail has a list of product? This is why you get the error message. In order to get products from ORDER_DETAILS you will need to iterate through it and get the products from each element.

You can try:

```
var orders = _uow.Repository<ORDERS>()
    .Query()
    .Where("PRODUCTS.HEADING.ToLower().Contains(\"foo\")")
    .Include(x=>x.ORDER_DETAILS.Select(y => y.PRODUCTS));
```

It seems like now you have the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties). Hope it works well now.

Comment: I guess I found a solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672050/dynamic-expression-tree-to-filter-on-nested-collection-properties. But still working on it.

Comment: Sorry for late response (it was holiday in my country). So actually we can't do your solution because in foreach loop order is actual item. We cannot use Include method or linq function there. Btw that unitofwork returns IQuerable.

Comment: Really, with the `Select` statement?

Comment: @Kadir I am pretty sure this should be working, can you try it again and keep me updated?

Comment: Nope, same result.