# Dynamic expression tree with method 'Select'

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to build the following lambda expression using the expression tree ->

```
info => info.event_objects.Select(x => x.object_info.contact_info)
```

I researched a lot and find some answers on the StackOverflow.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672050/dynamic-expression-tree-to-filter-on-nested-collection-properties/22685407#22685407) helped me to build the

```
info => 
     info.event_objects.Any(x => x.object_info.contact_info.someBool == true)
```

As you can see, the method 'Any' is easy to get.

```
var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Any" 
&& m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
anyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(childType);
```

The main problem is with the method 'Select'. If you will try to change the Name "Any" to "Select", you will get the following exception:

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == 
"Select" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
selectMethod = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(childType);
```

> Additional information: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Another way I've tried:

```
MethodInfo selectMethod = null;
foreach (MethodInfo m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name 
  == "Select"))
    foreach (ParameterInfo p in m.GetParameters().Where(p => 
           p.Name.Equals("selector")))
        if (p.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)
            selectMethod = (MethodInfo)p.Member;
```

It seems work, but then I get the exception here:

```
navigationPropertyPredicate = Expression.Call(selectMethod, parameter, 
navigationPropertyPredicate);

 Additional information: Method 
 System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TResult] Select[TSource,TResult] 
 (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], 
 System.Func`2[TSource,TResult]) is a generic method definition>
```

After that, I've tried to use:

```
selectMethod = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(event_objects), 
typeof(contact_info));
```

In fact, it doesn't help.

Here is my full code

```
 public static Expression GetNavigationPropertyExpression(Expression parameter, params string[] properties)
    {
        Expression resultExpression = null;
        Expression childParameter, navigationPropertyPredicate;
        Type childType = null;

        if (properties.Count() > 1)
        {
            //build path
            parameter = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);
            var isCollection = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.Type);
            //if it´s a collection we later need to use the predicate in the methodexpressioncall
            if (isCollection)
            {
                childType = parameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                childParameter = Expression.Parameter(childType, "x");
            }
            else
            {
                childParameter = parameter;
            }
            //skip current property and get navigation property expression recursivly
            var innerProperties = properties.Skip(1).ToArray();
            navigationPropertyPredicate = GetNavigationPropertyExpression(childParameter, innerProperties);
            if (isCollection)
            {
                //var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Select" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                //selectMethod = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(childType);
                MethodInfo selectMethod = null;
                foreach (MethodInfo m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Select"))
                    foreach (ParameterInfo p in m.GetParameters().Where(p => p.Name.Equals("selector")))
                        if (p.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)
                            selectMethod = (MethodInfo)p.Member;

                navigationPropertyPredicate = Expression.Call(selectMethod, parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
                resultExpression = MakeLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
            }
            else
            {
                resultExpression = navigationPropertyPredicate;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var childProperty = parameter.Type.GetProperty(properties[0]);
            var left = Expression.Property(parameter, childProperty);
            var right = Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool));
            navigationPropertyPredicate = Expression.Lambda(left);
            resultExpression = MakeLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
        }
        return resultExpression;
    }


    private static Expression MakeLambda(Expression parameter, Expression predicate)
    {
        var resultParameterVisitor = new ParameterVisitor();
        resultParameterVisitor.Visit(parameter);
        var resultParameter = resultParameterVisitor.Parameter;
        return Expression.Lambda(predicate, (ParameterExpression)resultParameter);
    }

    private class ParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public Expression Parameter
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            Parameter = node;
            return node;
        }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDynamicExpression()
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(event_info), "x");
        var expression = GetNavigationPropertyExpression(parameter, "event_objects", "object_info", "contact_info");
    }
```

Edit: unfortunately, I've tried answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753165/c-sharp-dynamically-generate-linq-select-with-nested-properties) question, but it doesn't seem work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# - Dynamically generate linq select with nested properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753165/c-sharp-dynamically-generate-linq-select-with-nested-properties)

Comment: Hope my aim was clear if someone considers that there isn't enough information regarding this, or something isn't understandable I will do my best to inform you as quickly as possible.

Comment: @mjwills I think that there are more than one select method found

Comment: @Emre, thanks, I checked those, but unfortunately couldn't apply this answer, as the implementation is different, or maybe I just missed something :(

Comment: @AlexZholob 1. `Select<TS, TR>(IE<TS> source, Func<TS, TR> selector)` 2. `Select<TS, TR>(IE<TS> source, Func<TS, int, TR> selector)` the second Select method is the overload which takes the "(item, index) => " selector lambda

Comment: @VladiPavelka, understood, but how can I get the proper select method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid finding the correct generic method overload via reflection (which is complicated and error prone as you already noticed) by using one of the two `Expression.Call` method overloads (one for `static` and one for `instance` methods) accepting `string methodName` and `Type[] typeArguments`.

Also the current implementation is overcomplicated and contains other problems, due to the lack of clear separation of expression and lambda expression building.

Here is a correct working implementation:

```
public static LambdaExpression GetNavigationPropertySelector(Type type, params string[] properties)
{
    return GetNavigationPropertySelector(type, properties, 0);
}

private static LambdaExpression GetNavigationPropertySelector(Type type, string[] properties, int depth)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, depth == 0 ? "x" : "x" + depth);
    var body = GetNavigationPropertyExpression(parameter, properties, depth);
    return Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
}

private static Expression GetNavigationPropertyExpression(Expression source, string[] properties, int depth)
{
    if (depth >= properties.Length)
        return source;
    var property = Expression.Property(source, properties[depth]);
    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.Type))
    {
        var elementType = property.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var elementSelector = GetNavigationPropertySelector(elementType, properties, depth + 1);
        return Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new Type[] { elementType, elementSelector.Body.Type },
            property, elementSelector);
    }
    else
    {
        return GetNavigationPropertyExpression(property, properties, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

The first is the public method. It internally uses the next two private methods to recursively build the desired lambda. As you can see, I distinguish between building lambda expression and just expression to be used as lambda body.

Test:

```
var selector = GetNavigationPropertySelector(typeof(event_info), 
    "event_objects", "object_info", "contact_info");
```

Result:

```
x => x.event_objects.Select(x1 => x1.object_info.contact_info)
```

Comment: Wow, it really works! Thank you man, I thought that it is impossible!

Answer (score 0):

> "Additional information: Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Unlike "Any()", for "Select()" there are two overloads with two parameters:

1. `Select<TS, TR>(IE<TS> source, Func<TS, TR> selector)`
2. `Select<TS, TR>(IE<TS> source, Func<TS, int, TR> selector)`
   (takes the "(item, index) => " selector lambda)

Since your code already relies on "esoteric knowledge" anyway, just take the first one of them:

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .First(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select) 
                 && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for now, I need to make select method generic using:
 selectMethod = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod().
But whatever I pass as the parameter to MakeGenericMethod(), I get exceptions. Is there any ideas?

Comment: I've tried the input and output parameters, but it doesn't seem work, and always through an exception

Comment: @Alex, `Select<TSource, TResult>()` is a generic method, with 2 generic parameters. To obtain the "constructed" version, you need to replace those 2 with a concrete type, say int & bool (to get `Select<int, bool>()`). That's actually what the [`MakeGenericMethod(Type[] typeArguments)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) is good for. Select has 2 generic parameters -> you need to call the MakeGenericMethod() with two type arguments